# Adding Value to cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

For the spreadsheet pictured below, I am trying to create a formula that will calculate the amount of shirts ordered for each size, then calculate the cost of each shirt ordered for a balance (total) owed. The problem I am having is the fact that there are 3 different prices for the shirts and various quantities that can be ordered. For example, one person can order 5 (YS) shirts or 1.

So basically I want to turn-("Derek Ranselle ordered (4) shirts, 1 for $10, 2 for $13 and 1 for $14  equaling $50)- into a formula and have the "Balance Owed" column to show that.

[image: spreadsheet screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You basically want the count of each price of shirt times the price, all added up. So in N41, put:

```
=SUM($C42:$G42)*$C$3+SUM($H42:$K42)*$H$3+SUM($L42)*$L$3
```

Then fill down. Each SUM is the sum of the counts of the shirts at a specific price, then it's multiplied by the price, and the three different amounts are added up, giving the total price.

Comment: THANK YOU, THNK YOU, THANK YOU!!!!! I was up til 2 am trying to figure this out YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER..... The absolute funny thing about this is as a wedding/party planner I use to have a program that did all this for me.....lol YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER!!!!!!

Comment: @KeenyaRobinson You're very welcome. And feel free to upvote the answer and mark it as accepted. :-)

Comment: To upvote I just click on the up arrow, so does that except it as well

Comment: @KeenyaRobinson There should be a gray arrow next to the answer (under the up and down vote arrows). Click that to accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @KeenyaRobinson:  You need at least 15 rep to upvote, but you can accept an answer that solves your problem by clicking on the checkmark.